# Deformation of particle objects

Tags: particles

When an object is added to particle system, it remains in original form. Is it possible to make so that these objects deform & wrap around mesh?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest I can get:

1. Make sure the particle object is a plane and has a good amount of subdivisions
   [image]
2. Name it with a unique name, like **'stick'**
3. Make a duplicate of Suzanne, remove the ParticleSystem from it (this is if you want to have the Subsurf modifier eventually on for Suzanne)
4. Apply the Subsurf modifier of the temporary particle-Suzanne, which leaves only the ParticleSystem to the modifier panel
5. (You may need to update the ParticleSystem by clicking the **'Seed'** value to 1, for example)
6. Click the **'Convert'** button in the ParticleSystem modifier
   [image]
7. A whole lot of stick objects are created to the scene
8. Delete the particle-Suzanne
9. In Outliner, search for **'stick.'**
10. Still in Outliner, select them all with <kbd>A</kbd>, then right-click one of them and click **'Select'**
11. Press <kbd>U</kbd> to make them unique, select **'Object & Data'**
12. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join them as one
13. Add **'Shrinkwrap'** and **'Solidify'** modifiers to it
    [image]
14. Maybe also 'Subsurf' modifier as well
15. There you have it
    [image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you! 
By the way, but what if need to use not plane, need use an object of a certain shape? Shrinkwrap won't work in this case.

Comment: Yep :/ That makes things a bit more harder. I don’t have much advice on that.

Comment: OK. But thanks anyway, that you helped.