# How can I model a mop head like this?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, photorealism

[image]
[image]

Hi Im trying to make something similar to a mop head like this. Im trying to model a character from the Don't hug me I'm scared show. But I couldnt figure out how to model his head.(At least realisticly).Thanks in advance If anyone wants to help ^^

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118220/deformation-of-particle-objects - I found this old answer which may help

Comment: I see.. I will look into this

Comment: In this case, important to know whether still or animated.

Comment: @RobinBetts I will rig this character so I might animate with it